# How to create empty directories using git-svn?

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to create a git repository from a part of an existing svn repo. I absolutely need to preserve empty directories. I have used the **--preserve-empty-dirs** options but it has not worked as I expected.

Here is the command that I used :

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --no-metadata --no-minimize-url --preserve-empty-dirs --authors-file=users.txt http://<url-to-svn-repo>/path/to/myproject/ myproject
```

After this finished running, I can see that no empty directories were created.
However looking in .git/config seems to indicate that the process successfully detected empty directories :

```
...
[svn-remote "svn"]
    noMetadata = 1
    preserve-empty-dirs = true
    placeholder-filename = .gitignore
    ...
    added-placeholder = <path-to-empty-directory-1>/.gitignore
    added-placeholder = <path-to-empty-directory-2>/.gitignore
    added-placeholder = <path-to-empty-directory-3>/.gitignore
    etc
```

Is there a way to tell git explicitly to create the directories that it listed and the .gitignore file inside each of them ?

Answer (score -1):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly in one run if you like. It also properly preserves empty directories by putting `.gitignore` files into them if you use the according commandline option `empty-dirs`.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: As far as I know svn2git does not have an option to preserve empty directories, so it does not help me.

`508 $ svn2git --empty-dirs
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/svn2git-2.4.0/lib/svn2git/migration.rb:151:in 'parse': invalid option: --empty-dirs (OptionParser::InvalidOption)`

Comment: You should reread my answer. You are **not** using the tool I referred to, but a same named tool. The one you are using is based on `git-svn` and thus suffers from many of the same drawbacks while working around some of them. If you are using the right tool, it has the option.

Comment: Btw. your config looks fine. The `fetch` (part of the `clone`) should have preserved the dirs. Of course not empty, but with a .gitignore file inside. There is no good way to fix this after the fetch, because even with a filter-branch you would need to know in which commits to add the directory and in which not.

Comment: Ah I see. I tried running `svn-all-fast-export` but it failed. Documentation seems lacking and geared towards KDE's specific svn. I'd rather stick to `git-svn` as it's more broadly used and documented much better.

Comment: What more do you need than https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git, https://techbase.kde.org/Projects/MoveToGit/UsingSvn2Git and probably https://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763? What failure did you get?

Comment: It is in no way KDE specific. It is all about getting the rules written according to your SVN layout.

Comment: The tool is not specific to kde, but the documentation is geared towards it. When I ran `svn-all-fast-export` it errored with the following : `svn: E000002: Can't open file '<path-to-svn-folder>/format': No such file or directory`

I think it fails because it needs to be run **on** the svn server and I am running it against a checkout. Unfortunately I cannot run this on the svn server :/

Comment: Yes, you need to run it agains an SVN repository of course, not a checkout. If you have access to the server, either simply download the repository directory or use `rsync` or `scp` or `sftp` for downloading. If you don't have access other than normal SVN access, use the `rsvndump` together with `svnadmin load` as described at https://github.com/hartwork/svneverever, the tool from the blog entry.